# designing data model similar to Power Point Presentation slides

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to come up with a data model that would adequately describe business rules, similar to power point presentations with one exception. The structure of the slides is predefined - each slide has a `slide style.` I need to store the contents the user inputed for that style (which image he/she chose, what is the String in heading 1 or 2...)

By `slide style` I mean that some slides have 1 heading, some 2, some 3 others, some have 1 image in it, others 8...some have a background video, some solid color, others backgorund image..

The order of slides in a presentation is also important. Users can add slides to presentation, remove them, replace them. One slide style can be repeated multiple times in a project. If you want to print the presentation, it gets printed in the correct order.

How would you construct such data model?

I've created `users` and `projects` table, but I am having problems with how to represent and `slide_style`. slide_style has so many different options and I see no elegant way of doing this. How would you do this?

`slide_style` and `project` are in M:N relationship, so I will create another table `project_slides` and link them together, but how to represent so many different styles is the real issue here.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `projects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: It sounds like you are getting caught up in the design, where the implementation will be quite different. Wouldn't your slide style just have a name, a few key words describing it, then a link to a blank slide file with a defined style?

Comment: I am definitively getting caught up in the design. Think of it this way. user chooses the slide style and I give him the appropriate inputs, so that he/she can fill in the headng 1, image 2 and so on... You must know which inputs a certain style needs. It may not need heading 4 and therefore I will not present an input for heading 4. Than I store the inputs, labeled with the correct style, so that when it is time to print - I can print everything necessary. And also in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to store a whole lot of information, as if you are creating an entire Powerpoint application. Not a bad thing, but as you have indicated you do not want to just use Slide Templates in files, you have to store everything about the Slide (both Templates and user Slides) in the database. This would enable you to reproduce the template on the fly based on the data saved once the user creates their own Presentation, based on a template.

I would approach this with a data model that uses an Entity-Attribute-Value method to store (what could be) a large number of Elements on your slides. The following is the data model I have come up with for you:

[image]

The interesting part, that you are probably struggling with, is on the right hand side of the model. SlideElement is an Element object that appears on your Slide. Each Element has a defined set of Attributes as described by the type of element you are adding.

This may not make much sense to you unless you see some example data as shown below:

[image]

So each Attribute defines the Attributes of an Element - an Element (could also be called "Control" or something similar) being a text box/picture/video, in the above data.  Elements are placed on Slides at particular locations, defined by the X/Y Position as described on the Element table and with a particular size (Length/Width). The Element entity, along with all the Attributes, is an instance of an Element, with its value described by the "Value" field. For a text box, the value would be its text/text size/colour/back colour etc, for videos/photos, their location/format/encoding/type etc.

Note the "PresentationType" field on the Presentation. I have put this as the identifier to decide if the file is a "Template" or "User" presentation. If the user chooses one of the Template files, the Presentation/Slide/SlideElement/Element rows would all be copied from the "Template" tables and re-inserted for the User tables. The default Element values would therefore be used to start with, with the user overwriting these as they work on their Slide design. The user would be able to move the elements around their slide as well, this would be reflected in the "SlideElement" table XYPos values as well as the size of the Element. The user could also add Elements, like a new text box or photo, which would create a new set of Element rows based on what was added. You would need a default list of Elements to add for each type, that step I haven't modelled but could be done easily.

Comment: Thank you so much. learned lots from this model. In the mean time, I also proceeded with design and came up with something that looks like it describes the logic adequately. I will post an image shortly.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1AKUv. The slide represents an instance of a slide. Each slide has a slide_style and that style is linked to read-only table slide_style_info. slide_style_info has key value pairs that describe the template. Actual user inputed content is stored in slide_content and background table. Overall this looks similar to what you proposed. I only cover predefined templates, no user generated temapltes